# How to use bool in Google maps listener?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, error-handling, boolean, dom-events

I stopped at this issue 4h, `if` ignores my bool when Google maps event invoked. I need to give in parameters different data. Maybe on the world someone know why?

`console.log` throws after click in same time:

```
true before click
stack.html:56[object HTMLDivElement]in listener
stack.html:62[object HTMLDivElement]bunga bunga
```

broken bool:

```
this.b = true;
...
console.log(this.b + " beafore click");
this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.b + "in listener");
    if (this.b==true) {
        console.log(this.b + "true works");
        tools[type](e.latLng, last_marker_origin);
        this.b = false;
    } else {
        console.log(this.b + "bunga bunga");
        //tools[type](e.latLng);
    }
});
```

`this` refers to "properties" in my object default set on false but when I change option it is flag to true.

I go to sleep for now. I'll answer in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` is no longer a valid reference to your `properties`. The simplest way to deal with your specific problem is to change the code:

```
this.b = true;
var props = this;
console.log(this.b + " beafore click");  //Notice that "this" is still valid here 
this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(props.b + "in listener");
    if (props.b == true) {
        console.log(props.b + "true works");
        tools[type](e.latLng, last_marker_origin);
        props.b = false;
    } else {
        console.log(props.b + "bunga bunga");
        //tools[type](e.latLng);
    }
});
```

The fundamental problem is that the code that actually makes the call to your callback function is in a completely different scope, so the meaning of `this` has changed when that code runs. Setting up a reference and putting that in the code will fix your problem.

Comment: I had to check today and it works. Thanks for the reply. You were first :)

Comment: It is amazing how many JavaScript problems boils down to problems with scope. It is hard to get into your head that it should be a problem, but once you realize it you will have a way easier time of writing JavaScript. Good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the scope of `this`. When you are inside the click event handler function `this` does no longer refer to your properties object, but to the event handler. The event handler is a so called [closure](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/).

There are two possible solutions for your problems.

1. Use a local variable (`var b` instead of `this.b`) for your value, local variables are copied in a closure, so the value can be used inside and outside of the closure:

   ```
   var b = true;
   console.log(b + " beafore click");
   this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
       console.log(b + "in listener");
       if (b==true) {
           console.log(b + "true works");
           tools[type](e.latLng, last_marker_origin);
           b = false;
       } else {
           console.log(b + "bunga bunga");
           //tools[type](e.latLng);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Save `this` in a local variable, this is a very common technique to avoid scoping problems:

   ```
   //save this in a locale variable, now 'me' provides access to this scope
   var me = this;
   me.b = true;
   console.log(me.b + " beafore click");
   this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
       console.log(me.b + "in listener");
       if (me.b==true) {
           console.log(me.b + "true works");
           tools[type](e.latLng, last_marker_origin);
           me.b = false;
       } else {
           console.log(me.b + "bunga bunga");
           //tools[type](e.latLng);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: The first option won't work because it won't set the value of the properties.b member to false.

Comment: That's true, but is not absolutely required. It's likely that you want to use the 2nd option, but if you only have one value, you'll be fine with the first one.